# SQLalchemy update data in SQlite using wtforms

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sql-update, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

**Hello everyone,**

I have a problem to edit my data using a wtforms, SQLAlchemy and SQlite3. I have generated a form and can query the data filtered by ID. The form is perfectly filled with corresponding data. But when I change the data and press submit it won't update the data. There are actually two problems. First the forms don't pass the new typed data back to python and variables, and second i can't figure how to update the current selected row of data.

Here's is my code:

```
@app.route('/sensorlist_edit/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def sensorlist_edit(id):
    sensor = Sensor.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    form = SensorListForm(request.form)
    form.name.data = sensor.name
    form.sensor_type.data = str(sensor.sensor_type)
    form.pin.data = sensor.pin
    form.limit_temp_up.data = sensor.limit_temp_up
    form.limit_temp_down.data = sensor.limit_temp_down
    form.limit_hum_up.data = sensor.limit_hum_up
    form.limit_hum_down.data = sensor.limit_hum_down
    form.limit_aqua_temp_up.data = sensor.limit_aqua_temp_up
    form.limit_aqua_temp_down.data = sensor.limit_aqua_temp_down

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = form.name.data
        sensor_type = int(form.sensor_type.data)
        pin = form.pin.data
        limit_temp_up = form.limit_temp_up.data
        limit_temp_down = form.limit_temp_down.data
        limit_hum_up = form.limit_hum_up.data
        limit_hum_down = form.limit_hum_down.data
        limit_aqua_temp_up = form.limit_aqua_temp_up.data
        limit_aqua_temp_down = form.limit_aqua_temp_down.data

        db.session.commit()

        flash('You updated a sensor', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('sensorlist_CRUD'))
    return render_template('sensorlist_edit.html', form=form)
```

The model class is generated with this code:

```
class Sensor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    sensor_type = db.Column(db.Integer)
    pin = db.Column(db.Integer)
    limit_temp_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_temp_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_hum_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_hum_down = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_aqua_temp_up = db.Column(db.Float)
    limit_aqua_temp_down = db.Column(db.Float)
```

And here is the Jinja template form the wtforms:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
  <h2><b>Edit Sensor</b></h2>
  {% from "includes/_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.name, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.sensor_type, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.pin, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.limit_temp_up, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.limit_temp_down, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.limit_hum_up, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.limit_hum_down, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.limit_aqua_temp_up, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{render_field(form.limit_aqua_temp_down, class_="form-control")}}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I use exactly the same form, model, python-code and template (with other .html) for the adding of data to the database, and that works perfectly.

I hope someone could help me with what i'm missing, or could give me a link of short description of what i'm doing wrong. I searched already multiple threads and other posts, but can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance for every help you give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, in your code under the `POST` block you need to update the actual model... right now you are just setting a bunch of variables with the form data but it isn't getting applied to the model. Like this:

```
@app.route('/sensorlist_edit/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def sensorlist_edit(id):
    sensor = Sensor.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    form = SensorListForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        sensor.name = form.name.data
        sensor.sensor_type = int(form.sensor_type.data)
        sensor.pin = form.pin.data
        sensor.limit_temp_up = form.limit_temp_up.data
        sensor.limit_temp_down = form.limit_temp_down.data
        sensor.limit_hum_up = form.limit_hum_up.data
        sensor.limit_hum_down = form.limit_hum_down.data
        sensor.limit_aqua_temp_up = form.limit_aqua_temp_up.data
        sensor.limit_aqua_temp_down = form.limit_aqua_temp_down.data

        db.session.commit()

        flash('You updated a sensor', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('sensorlist_CRUD'))

    form.name.data = sensor.name
    form.sensor_type.data = str(sensor.sensor_type)
    form.pin.data = sensor.pin
    form.limit_temp_up.data = sensor.limit_temp_up
    form.limit_temp_down.data = sensor.limit_temp_down
    form.limit_hum_up.data = sensor.limit_hum_up
    form.limit_hum_down.data = sensor.limit_hum_down
    form.limit_aqua_temp_up.data = sensor.limit_aqua_temp_up
    form.limit_aqua_temp_down.data = sensor.limit_aqua_temp_down

    return render_template('sensorlist_edit.html', form=form)
```

#### Update:

I moved the form assignments below the `POST` section as I think they were overwriting the submitted form data with the old information... sorry I missed that the first time through!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Strange enough it has no effect... When i pass a flash message with the variable in it, it still passes the data from the database, and not the new typed data in the form? It looks like the form, when filled with data from the database, don't except new data in the form fields when typed in.

Comment: You're still missing `db.session.add(sensor)`. Another note, it's better to do `sensor = Sensor.query.get_or_404(id)`, so if the user edits the id in the url to some bogus data you won't get an error in your script.

Comment: you don't need to add an existing object back to the session... you only need to use `db.session.add(...)` if you are adding a new record to the table, if you query to receive the record, as the OP does, this is not needed

Comment: @Thijs see updates... I think you were overwriting the new posted form data with the old database information... give this a try and I think it will solve your problem

Comment: @abigperson Salvation!!! Thanks, that was the last piece of the puzzle. It works perfectly now. Thanks for the help and time. And thanks everyone for sharing their thoughts